PHP - Argument #3 ($modifier) must be of type callable, string given
I am trying to store a callable/closure as a class field/property.
My initial attempt was this:
class MyClass
{
    protected callable $modifier;

    public function __construct(callable $modifier) {
        $this->modifier = $modifier;
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static function func()
    {
        return ['a' => 'b'];
    }
}

$test = new MyClass('SomeOtherClass::func');

This returned an error of:

$modifier cannot have type callable

Then, after reading this online, I've tried this with no success:
class MyClass
{
    protected Closure $modifier;

    public function __construct(callable $modifier) {
        $this->modifier = Closure::fromCallable($modifier);
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static function func()
    {
        return ['a' => 'b'];
    }
}

$test = new MyClass('SomeOtherClass::func');

This last one returns this error:

Argument #1 ($modifier) must be of type callable, string given

Then I've tried this:
class MyClass
{
    protected Closure $modifier;

    public function __construct(callable $modifier) {
        $this->modifier = Closure::fromCallable($modifier);
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static function func()
    {
        return ['a' => 'b'];
    }
}

$test = new MyClass(['SomeOtherClass', 'func']); // <----- changed string to an array

Which returns this error:

Argument #1 ($modifier) must be of type callable, array given

Is this even possible to do in PHP?

As it relates specifically to callable as type hinting, it was explicitly forbidden on properties because it is context-dependent

func is an instance method, so you must provide an instance.

@shingo Yes, you are right. This problem was introduced to the sample code by accident. The original code I have is OK. I will update the question.

Assuming you're using PHP 8.1 or above (which at the time of writing are the only supported versions of PHP anyway), then you can use first-class callable syntax, as introduced in 8.1.
To do this, you use the name of a function and then (...) as the argument to pass in.
In your case, you could therefore do this:
class MyClass
{
    protected Closure $modifier;

    public function __construct(callable $modifier) {
        $this->modifier = Closure::fromCallable($modifier);
    }
    
    public function runClosure()
    {
        var_dump(($this->modifier)());
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static function func()
    {
        return ['a' => 'b'];
    }
}

$test = new MyClass(SomeOtherClass::func(...));
$test->runClosure();

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/nMmvq

N.B. The code above assumes that you want to use func() as a static method (as defined in your sample code). If anyone is reading and wants to do something similar but with an instance method, you'd need a small adjustment as follows:
class MyClass
{
    protected Closure $modifier;

    public function __construct(callable $modifier) {
        $this->modifier = Closure::fromCallable($modifier);
    }

    public function runClosure()
    {
        var_dump(($this->modifier)());
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public function func()
    {
        return ['a' => 'b'];
    }
}

$soc = new SomeOtherClass();
$test = new MyClass($soc->func(...));
$test->runClosure();

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/iEAiM

Just for the sake of completeness. The problem in OP's code was most likely caused by namespaces.
You have to use fully qualified name in array/string callable. So, you have to use  [SomeOtherClass::class, 'func'] or ['\MyNamespace\SomeOtherClass', 'func'].
See live demo: https://3v4l.org/pnWYC

Interesting. Things become too hard to figure out when the error message is wrong...

The error message is not exactly wrong in this case. Only array that references existing class/method is considered "callable". It couldn't find the class \SomeOtherClass and that's why the value was considered regular array and not callable.
